# Android Spring ClassNotFoundException For ObjectMapper

Tags: java, android, spring, jackson, spring-android

I'm having this annoying exception in my Android project. What I'm trying to do is to post json to my rest service. My problem is that I can't use the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter. Whatever I do it keeps throwing an exception:

```
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924): Process: com.restclient.trafficspy, PID: 12924
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper;
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:55)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    at com.restclient.trafficspy.RestServiceClient.doInBackground(RestServiceClient.java:51)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    at com.restclient.trafficspy.RestServiceClient.doInBackground(RestServiceClient.java:1)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    ... 4 more
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.restclient.trafficspy-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    ... 9 more
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):        ... 10 more
04-27 19:58:33.124: E/AndroidRuntime(12924):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I'm not using Maven or Gradle and I don't want to. Here are tha jars that I have added. I don't think I'm missing something.

[image]

Do you have any idea what causes the problem and how to fix it? Feel free to ask if you need more information. Thanks!

Comment: How about reading the doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring-android/docs/current/reference/html/rest-template.html#MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

Answer (score 0):

Okey, It worked when I changed MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to GsonHttpMessageConverter. This doesn't solve the ClassNotFoundException problem but it is a solution that works for me.